# WSL2 on Microsoft Surface Pro X

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, microsoft-surface-pro

I purchased MS Surface Pro X and updated Windows to Version 1903 (OS Build 19018.1) using the Insider Program. I followed the WSL2 doc and installed Ubuntu 18.04 for ARM.

Everything seemed fine but WSL works only in cmd not in Powershell(Admin mode). The wsl.exe is in C:\Windows\System32 and Powershell can't see the file.

The error message is:

```
The term 'wsl' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or oparable program.
```

I run WSL2 on my other computers without any problem. Only this device has the issue.

Please advise.

[Edit]

This is the result of 'winver' command:

[image]

This is from 'cmd':

[image]

This is from 'powershell':

[image]

[Edit #2]

PATH from cmd as Administrator
C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd;C:\Users\ssk\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\ssk\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin

PATH from Powershell as Administrator
C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd;C:\Users\ssk\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\ssk\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> I purchased MS Surface Pro X and updated Windows to Version 1903 (OS Build 19018.1) using the Insider Program. I followed the WSL2 doc and installed Ubuntu 18.04 for ARM.

You are absolutely NOT running **Windows 10 version 1903**.  There are multiple reasons I know what version you are actually running.

However, your inability to run WSL from a PowerShell prompt is a known issue, you need to run it from a command prompt.

> If you are using an Arm64 device and running this command from
>   PowerShell, you will receive this error. Instead, run wsl.exe from
>   PowerShell Core, or Command Prompt.

Source: [Installation Instructions for WSL 2](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl2-install#troubleshooting)

It appears that in the future Hyper-V will be supported on ARM devices once `Windows 10 version 2103` is released.

Source: [Windows 10 Version 2103](https://www.changewindows.org/milestones/21h1/pc)