# PowerShell Core 7 cannot find WSL

Tags: windows-10, powershell-core

I upgraded my Windows 10 version to 2004 and installed Ubuntu in WSL 2. I can start it from PowerShell (via `wsl`). I can start it from CMD. I can see `wsl.exe` in `C:\Windows\System32`. It is definitely there. However I can not start it via PowerShell Core (v7.1.0-preview.3), the command is not recognized.

The really part is that I can also not find it via `ls` in PowerShell Core, but in PowerShell. Is this a weird bug? It sounds a little to specific for me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WSL2 on Microsoft Surface Pro X](https://superuser.com/questions/1501598/wsl2-on-microsoft-surface-pro-x)

Comment: Do you have a x86 device or an ARM64 device?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by updating my version of PowerShell Core as suggested [here](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/12857).