# Powershell doesn't find certain files

Tags: windows, command-line, file-shortcut, powershell-core

I've recently run into an issue where Powershell (and only Powershell) refuses to run certain files. Outside Powershell, such as in explorer or in cmd, everything works fine.

But in Powershell (version 7.0.3) certain `.lnk` files (which I *do* have on my `$env:PATHEXT`) fail with a `ResourceUnavailable: Program '[name]' failed to run.` error, and certain (unrelated) `.exe` files don't seem to exist at all - that may be the case for other files as well, but I haven't noticed any yet.

This happens whether or not I provide the full paths to the files in question, and regardless of whether they are currently on my `$env:Path`.

Here's a comparison in cmd for one of the affected `.exe` files

```
D:\>C:\Windows\system32\wsl.exe --list
Windows Subsystem for Linux Distributions:
Ubuntu-20.04 (Default)

D:\>pwsh -c "C:\Windows\system32\wsl.exe --list"
C:\Windows\system32\wsl.exe: The term 'C:\Windows\system32\wsl.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

and here's one of the affected `.lnk` files

```
D:\>gimp.lnk --license && echo Runs fine!
Runs fine!

D:\>pwsh -c "gimp.lnk --license && 'Runs fine!'"
ResourceUnavailable: Program 'Gimp.lnk' failed to run: Det går inte att hitta sökvägen.At line:1 char:1
+ gimp.lnk --license && 'Runs fine!'
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~.

D:\>pwsh -c "& 'C:\Program Files\GIMP 2\bin\gimp-2.10.exe' <# The shortcut target #> --license && 'Runs fine!'"
Runs fine!
```

Edit: Updating to the v7.1.0 preview as suggested in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1557132) did not fix either problem.

What is going on here and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that I have an x64 processor but installed the x86 version of Powershell. Both issues were resolved by installing the x64 version of Powershell instead.

Comment: Had a similar issue where cmd.exe could find and open a directory, but Powershell x86 couldn't locate that directory. Switching to Powershell x64 solved the problem for me.