# How do I set up and use WSL on Windows 10 and a Linux distro in a virtual machine?

Tags: powershell, wsl2

I have installed WSL 2 on my Windows 10. I have a Debian system. Things work fine.

I want to launch WSL from a PowerShell terminal, so I type the command `wsl`.
I get the error:

```
PS C:\Users\MyUser> wsl
wsl : The term 'wsl' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of
the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ wsl
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (wsl:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Why is that?

**Update**
Strange enough, when I try to get the command, I have a negative answer:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-Command wsl -All
Get-Command : The term 'wsl' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-Command wsl -All
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (wsl:String) [Get-Command], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetCommandCommand
```

Still, the executable `wsl.exe` is in `C:\Windows\Syste32`, where it should be...

If I set an alias with:

```
Set-Alias -Name wsl -Value C:\Windows\system32\wsl.exe
```

nothing changes in the output when I run `wsl` (I get the same error).

Windows specifics:

- Edition Windows 10 Pro
- Version 2004
- OS build 19041.572

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux


FeatureName      : Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux
DisplayName      : Windows Subsystem for Linux
Description      : Provides services and environments for running native user-mode Linux shells and tools on Windows.
RestartRequired  : Possible
State            : Enabled
CustomProperties :
                   ServerComponent\Description : Provides services and environments for running native user-mode Linux shells and
                   tools on Windows.
                   ServerComponent\DisplayName : Windows Subsystem for Linux
                   ServerComponent\Id : 1033
                   ServerComponent\Type : Feature
                   ServerComponent\UniqueName : Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux
                   ServerComponent\Deploys\Update\Name : Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux
```

Comment: Do you by chance of a machine with an ARM processor. [I have only seen this behavior before with an ARM device running Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1501598/wsl2-on-microsoft-surface-pro-x/1501609#1501609). 
Please edit your question to include the necessary information to answer your question.  I am able to launch WSL2 from a PowerShell prompt on my 2004 and 20H2 machine

Comment: My machine has an Intel Core i7 processor...

Comment: What build exactly do you have installed?  You can retrieve this information by running `winver`  Please run the following command `Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux` in an elevated PowerShell command prompt and provide an edit your question

Comment: I ran the same commands you ran, and I do not have WSL installed on the machine, and got the same results.  This tells me Windows Subsystem for Linux is not actually installed.  The command I provide will indicate if it's installed or not.

Comment: You can see the output of the command in the updated question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the command

```
wslconfig.exe /l
```

gave as response

```
Windows Subsystem for Linux Distributions:
docker-desktop-data
docker-desktop
Debian
```

I noticed that the default was not set. Therefore, I simply set the default:

```
wslconfig.exe /setdefault "Debian"
```

Now with  `wslconfig.exe /l` I get:

```
Windows Subsystem for Linux Distributions:
Debian (Default)
docker-desktop-data
docker-desktop
```

and I am able to launch WSL 2 default distro with `wsl`.

Answer (score 0):

This is really not a Powershell code question, but a 'How do I set up and use WSL on Windows 10 and a Linux distro in a virtual machine?'

WSL is a service...

> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10

... allowing Linux distros to run on Windows 10. It is not an app/command to run from PowerShell. So, that error is pretty specific. You distro must be running!

Have you reviewed and leverage the needed steps as shown in videos...

- [WSL 2: Getting started](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_fntjriRe48)
- [How to Install & Enable WSL in Windows 10 (+ how to access
  files)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5RTSlby-l9w)
- [How to install WSL 2 on Windows 10 with Powershell](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0tn-wJGqPOg)

...to get WSL configured ...

```
(Get-CimInstance -ClassName CIM_OperatingSystem).Version
# Results
<#
10.0.19041
#>


$PSVersionTable
# Results
<#
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.19041.546
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 5.1.19041.546}
BuildVersion                   10.0.19041.546
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
#>

# Results
<#
Get-Command -Name wsl.exe

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Application     wsl.exe                                            10.0.19... C:\WINDOWS\system32\wsl.exe
#>

Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux
# Results
<#
FeatureName      : Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux
DisplayName      : Windows Subsystem for Linux
Description      : Provides services and environments for running native user-mode Linux shells and tools on Windows.
RestartRequired  : Possible
State            : Enabled
CustomProperties :
                   ServerComponent\Description : Provides services and environments for running native user-mode Linux shells and tools on
                   Windows.
                   ServerComponent\DisplayName : Windows Subsystem for Linux
                   ServerComponent\Id : 1033
                   ServerComponent\Type : Feature
                   ServerComponent\UniqueName : Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux
                   ServerComponent\Deploys\Update\Name : Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux
#>
```

...and your distro configured to use that Linux distro.

```
wsl --list --verbose
Windows Subsystem for Linux has no installed distributions.
Distributions can be installed by visiting the Microsoft Store:
https://aka.ms/wslstore
```

Comment: Well, each single command returns *precisely* the same output as yours. Still, I cannot start WSL 2 from a PowerShell by typing `wsl`.

Comment: @EM90 - It should; I have seen strange behavior when a reboot was required. I assume you have tried that?  Otherwise, I would remove and add Windows Subsystem for Linux and see if that resolves the problem

Comment: Yeah, I definitely tried the reboot. Still nothing changes. As soon as I can, I'll go with your remove-and-add WSL advice. Thanks.