# WSL command provides no output when run in Administrator console

Tags: windows-10, powershell, cmd.exe, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

I can run wsl commands `'wsl -l' etc` from both command prompt, and powershell with no issue when the consoles are opened with user permissions.

WSL command working in non-admin console:
[image]

However, when I run attempt to run wsl commands from a console ran an Administrator, the command provides no output and immediately stops. (This is behavior is independent of the directory being run from)

WSL commands not working in admin console:
[image]

Running `where wsl` shows that it points to `C:\Windows\System32\wsl.exe` for both admin and non-admin consoles.

This is on windows version 21H2, build 19044.1766

I need to be able to run wsl commands as an admin to be able to perform a `wsl --update`.

Comment: You will need to provide more information about the device.  I have seen this behavior before[.](https://superuser.com/questions/1501598/wsl2-on-microsoft-surface-pro-x?rq=1)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Ramhound This looks to be the exact *opposite* of the question you marked as a duplicate.  This is about problems when running as admin - The other is about problems when *not* running as admin.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds - In my experience the problem is caused by the same underline problem but since it’s your answer I’ll trust your experience. The god awful answer is one reason I went looking for a duplicate

Comment: @Ramhound Agreed that my answer there was more of a blind shot than anything, and if we go from the lack of an "Accept", not the right one.  I'm sure there are good answers to the Administrator/users issue with WSL, but I'm not sure what the pattern is yet.

Comment: Most users don’t accept answers, I have answers with 50 up votes, that are unaccepted. Up to us as subject matter semi-experts to determine if an existing answer answers a question